# HibernateException: No Session found for current thread when GORM query moved into another domain class

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In grails, I  have a Domain class and can be queried in BootStap.groovy

```
def xref = AppXref.find{user_nm == 'john'}
```

However, once I moved the code into a method of another Domain class I will have the following error.

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/myapp] threw exception
Message: Could not obtain current Hibernate Session; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
```

Here is my hibernate config in Config.groovy

```
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
    flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context
}
```

I changed cache.use_query_cache  to true. But it made no difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

domain class methods are NOT transactional, so you have to make sure, that they are invoked in a TX-context: either put them in a service, or use `.withTransaction{}`

Comment: what was the solution?

Comment: Sorry to downvote but for the answer nor for the original asker comment it's very difficult to infere how to apply the solution.

Answer (score 13):

Adding `@Transactional` on the method worked for me.

Comment: This is the right answer because its the simplest change to fix the problem.

Comment: I upvoted both answers because this is good, but the other is nice when you are not in service, and you dont want to care about it.