# Grails Hibernate session unavailable in quartz job?

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, hibernate-session

I am working on an small Grails application which leverages the Quartz plugin for scheduled tasks.  It seems that my quartz job does not have access to the hibernate session.  Below is the exception.

> Caused by DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not obtain current
>   Hibernate Session; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

Versions : Grails 2.4.4, Quartz 1.0.1 and Hibernate 4.3.6.1

Is there a work around?  Is this a Grails upgrade issue?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what happens if you wrap your call around withNewSession { ? https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-312

Comment: What version of Hibernate?

Comment: looks like withNewSession will work.  Thanks

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27724465/hibernateexception-no-session-found-for-current-thread-when-gorm-query-moved-in/42135369#42135369