# Grails 3.0.1 and Hibernate Session error

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am following a book example (Grails in Action 2nd edition) which is based on Grails 2.* but I am using the new Grails 3.0.1.

When I create a domain class that looks like:

```
package qotd

class Quote {
   String content
   String author
   Date created = new Date()
}
```

I get an Exception thrown whenever I try to interact with the DB through the groovy console.

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not obtain current Hibernate Session;
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
```

I have tried to add @Transactional to the domain class and also swith to a lower JDK version(7) but none of them works.
I have also tested with Grails 3.0 and results are same.
If I downgrade to Grails 2.5.0 it works so it is a Grails 3.* issue. Gradle could be the issue.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27724465/hibernateexception-no-session-found-for-current-thread-when-gorm-query-moved-in/42135369#42135369

Answer (score 7):

I wrapped everything inside a transaction for Grails 3

```
qotd.Quote.withTransaction {
  new qotd.Quote(author: 'Larry Wall',
    content: 'There is more than one method to our madness.').save()
}
```