# GORM not working. Getting error Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

My code looks like this:

```
def get(Long id){
    return Client.findById(id);
}
```

When this method is called  I got an error like this

```
2015-12-01 19:00:25,529 Failure execution thread for 1448974681594
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: 
Could not obtain current Hibernate Session;
nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: 
No Session found for current thread
```

I'm using grails 2.5.1 and The Hibernate plugin ":hibernate4:4.3.8.1"

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information about where the `get(Long id)` method is and where it's being called from. Otherwise there isn't enough information here to answer your question.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27724465/hibernateexception-no-session-found-for-current-thread-when-gorm-query-moved-in/42135369#42135369

Answer (score 1):

The error is descriptive. Thread that executes your code (`get(...)`) doesn't have hibernate session bound to it. Maybe you execute it asynchronously in new thread, thread pool, etc ?

If yes, you can fix it with:

```
def get(Long id){
    return Client.withSession {
        return Client.findById(id);
    }    
}
```

But rather do this on top level where your asynchronous flow starts.